# Licensing Android Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, android, licensing, apache-commons-math

I am about to release my first commercial software ever. I didnt study something related to programming so i am facing a problem here, which is licensing. I am not native english speaking, so i have a little bit of a problem when i read the Apache Commons License.

In my software i use the Apache Commons Math library. If i understand their FAQ i just may distribute my software if i add this (the text will come up at my "info" screen inside the app):

```
    [...]        
    \nCopyright 2012 xxxstefplexxxx

    \n\n This software uses Apache Commons Math Library
    \nThe license can be found here:
    \nhttp://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    \n
```

Is that all i need to do if i want to use the above library ?

Do i need to apply any license on my software ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and in any other place in your software that displays copyright notices. Also I believe that technically you are supposed to include a copy of the license on your programs distribution media, whether thats a cd or a zip file, etc (although this may not make sense for an android app, so I'm sure just the about screen would be an appropriate place to place the information). It does not require you to license your code under any particular license.

See also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007338/can-i-use-a-library-under-the-apache-software-license-2-0-in-a-commercial-applic)

Comment: Thanks, i will add the whole license in the folder i create on the sdcard.